# Passing a variable from $_GET to another page

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have am trying to do a simple search bar. The query that is entered into the search is pulled to another page. That works perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I try to use that variable in a script that increments the query's row in the database table. Everything works fine when I just put the name of a table element in instead of the variable, but I need to grab what they searched for to be able to get it to work properly.

I think you can do this with a session, but I don't want to bother with sessions for such a small project.

This is how I pull the variable from the search bar:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
```

That works fine, but I can't get it to a new page to use in this piece of code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET Sold=Sold+1 WHERE Brand='Skittles' OR Type='Candy'");
```

Comment: We need more background information on this.  Can you provide more details on the type of query you are working with and how it ties into your search and db query?

Comment: Are sessions really that big a deal?

Comment: You would have to update all links on the page to include that in the query string

Comment: probably less work to use sessions than the above.

Comment: Remember parsing your query will be harmful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are fairly easy to work with.

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['query'] = $_GET['query'];

?>
```

That would store it, then to retrieve it use it just like you would `$_GET['query']` but use `$_SESSION['query']`.  It'll persist until the session expires or is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the query as a parameter to the other page if you really want to use it there :

```
next_page.php?query=something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the query on say nextpage.php from currentpage.php

currentpage.php:

`$query = $_GET['query'];`

`echo "<script> 
var url = nextpage.php?query=" . $query . ";
onSomeEvent=function(){window.location.assign(url);};
</script>"`;

This url can be used when you refer to nextpage.php and the value can then be accessed in nextpage.php as:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
```

Setting unnecessary data as session variable is not a good idea. For more see:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided